# What's the type of light that uses 2 switches to have 3 stages of brightness?

Tags: lighting

I have an exhaust fan with a light in it. The light has two switches (probably each one controls a separate light).

| Dim switch | Bright switch | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Off | Off | Off |
| On | Off | Dim |
| Off | On | Bright |
| On | On | Very bright |

What is this kind of lighting system called? I can't find it despite my Googling and asking AI.

Comment: If just one light, then that used to be called a three way light, but they usually used one switch with off, low, medium, high.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-way_lamp

Answer (score 2):

You're describing the logic of “3-way lighting" as used in the context of desk and floor lamps.  (Not to be confused with multiple distant switches built into building wiring that control the same light).

This generally uses a special pull chain switch or twist-switch that has 4 positions.  But I suppose 2 switch positions could be done, the UX would just be awkward.

It uses a special socket that has an intermediate contact for the other filament.

Some LED replacements for these 3-way bulbs change the sequence to off-low-*high*-medium, so if the bulb is used in a non-equipped socket, it gives high instead of medium.

Comment: No reason to suppose it because the OP stated the light has two switches. :-)

Comment: That interface sounds like it was designed by a programmer. Brightness is a 2-bit binary variable here

Answer (score 0):

There's no definite name for that configuration. It's usually referred to as multilevel illumination on the packaging.